# Opening multiple tabs by submitting multiple forms at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a page that helps with printing packing slips. It will divide up the packing slips by country. So for example we will end up with two different forms, one for US, one for CA.

```
<form id="US" class="packingSlipForm" action="magical_url" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input id="id_US" name="country" value="US" type="hidden" class="accountLocalID">
    <input name="orders[0]" value="552269" type="hidden" class="orderFormItem">
    <input name="orders[1]" value="552273" type="hidden" class="orderFormItem">
    <input name="orders[2]" value="552276" type="hidden" class="orderFormItem">
    <input name="orders[3]" value="537048" type="hidden" class="orderFormItem">
    <input name="orders[4]" value="541181" type="hidden" class="orderFormItem">
</form>

<form id="CA" class="packingSlipForm" action="magical_url" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input id="id_CA" name="country" value="CA" type="hidden" class="accountLocalID">
    <input name="orders[0]" value="553351" type="hidden" class="orderFormItem">
</form>
```

and this is my script to submit the forms.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printPackingSlips() {
        $(".packingSlipForm").each(function () {
            this.submit();
        });
    }
</script>
```

I'd like it to open two different tabs with the data from each form submit. But instead it opens one tab and only shows data from whatever form was submitted last.

Any ideas on how to make each form open it's own tab?

Comment: I suggest you rethink what you're doing. It is very unusual and visitors might nog like it at all. Maybe show it on one page in two columns/tabs/below eachother?

Comment: Use a couple of Ajax requests instead.

Comment: If it has to be two different tabs then set it up so that even if visually it is two forms, it is actually just a single form. When the form is submitted, process the first form part and pass the second form part on to another tab for further processing.

Comment: Try using two different `target` attributes. Either one in `_blank` the other in `_self` or each with a distinct framename.